# Como implementar o voltar no Webview do Android

Tags: android

Tenho uma Activity do Android com apenas uma webview dentro.
Por exemplo:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Como eu faço o webview voltar para tela anterior quando eu clicar no botão fisico de voltar do telefone?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa sobrescrever o evento de voltar da sua Activity e implementar o voltar do webview se ele puder voltar.
Por exemplo:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (this.webView.canGoBack()) {
        this.webView.goBack();
    } else {
        this.finish();
    }
}
```